# Rename "Documents" folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, my-documents

I use a different name for "Documents" folder.

Previously I had to rename it after every windows update, because updates kept changing it back.

Now I am unable to rename it to the same old name anymore. 
After typing the name and pressing enter, it stays "Documents", without displaying any message. But I still can give it any other name I don't want :)

Is there a way to use my old relevant name?

Comment: You mean to say that you can rename it to other names but not with your desired one?

Comment: exactly. I have used that specific name for more than a year, but every windows update used to change it back to "Documents".

Comment: Did you try to change it with other name you don't want and then again rename it your desired one.

Comment: Is there already a folder that exists with the desired name?

Comment: @avirk: yes, I tried renaming it from another name than default.

Comment: @DarthAndroid: in "Libraries" dropdown there is no folder named like this, but I`m not sure, what type of objects these "Libraries" are in the filesystem...

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas A folder not appearing in Libraries does not mean it doesn't exist in the same location where My Documents exist i.e c:\users\username\

Answer (score 4):

Navigate into the folder you want to rename and look for `desktop.ini`.
Open it in any text editor and you'll find this line

```
LocalizedResourceName=@shell32.dll,-##### (a number)
```

Now change the string after the equal sign to whatever you want, like this

```
LocalizedResourceName=My Custom Name
```

Save and quit. It is not necessary, but recommended, that you set the file to read-only in 'Properties'.

Comment: I use this solution to rename it to "Not documents". Then, I mark the file as read-only.

Comment: Still works in Windows 11, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## First of all: *can* you create such a folder?

First of all, make sure you **can** create a folder with the desired name.

Try it upfront: right-click the parent folder, then click **New**, then click **Folder**, then type in the desired name, and then press `Enter`.

Had success? Ok, delete (or not) the created folder.

Could you not create the folder? Try running `CHKDSK` or, if it didn't work, look for any clues at the `eventvwr.msc`

### Ok, a folder with the desired name *can* be created

You may try changing the default location of 'My Documents'.

Following (more or less) the instructions from Microsoft (at http://goo.gl/EWvhh0).

1. right-click the current 'Documents' folder (the one you want to rename)
2. click **Properties**, and then click the **Location** tab
3. change the path in the text box to the desired one, and then click **Apply**
4. Windows will then:

   4.1. try to create the new folder (if it does not exist)
   4.2. move the files from the original folder to the new one
   4.3. and assume the new folder as THE 'My Documents' folder

If Windows fails at step '4.1', well, man, it's past the time for a clean setup.

(Anyways, this question is so old that I doubt @JustinasDūdėnas still needs it to be answered, that he still is using the troubled Windows 7 setup...)

Comment: OP is not trying to **rename** the Documents folder & moving it would not help it

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like, you have a point. I rewrote my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One work-around to this issue of renaming and the issue of Documents always reverting it's name after updates may be to simply create a shortcut to the documents folder and rename the shortcut. Place the shortcut where ever you like.